# Keyless cipher proof

Tags: encryption, classical-cipher

I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72752760/how-to-reverse-code-this-linear-transformation-algorithm/72765495#72765495) on StackOverflow yesterday that was asking why the following keyless encoding/decoding scheme for 16-bit numbers worked:

#### Encoding

- Note that the "shift" operation is a rotational shift, not just an arithmetic shift.
- Note also that I am using $\oplus$ to indicate a bitwise $XOR$ operation.

$$ L(m) = m \oplus (m<<6)\oplus(m<<10)  $$

#### Decoding

$$ m = L \oplus ( L<<2 ) \oplus ( L<<4 ) \oplus ( L<<12 ) \oplus ( L<<14 ) $$

The way I takled the problem was by brute force expanding $(L<<n)$ in terms of $m$ and noticing how all the factors cancel out leaving $m = m$ at the end (you can see all the steps in my Stack Overflow answer).

However, I was unable to find a mathematical proof for it, because I could not generalize the XOR and rotate operations. Could you help me? I think the proof might involve Galois Field and how we define XOR and rotate over the $\{0,1\}^p$ set, but I am clueless after this intuition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we identify the 16-bit word $m=m_{15}\ldots m_0$ with the $GF(2)$ polynomial $m(X):=m_{15}X^{15}\oplus\cdots m_1X\oplus m_0$, then XORing words corresponds to addition of polynomials and rotation by $k$ positions corresponds to multiplying by $X^k$ and reducing mod $X^{16}\oplus 1$.

In polynomial land therefore the operation $L(m)$ corresponds to multiplying $m(X)$ by the polynomial $1\oplus X^6\oplus X^{10}$ and reducing mod $X^{16}\oplus 1$. To reverse the operation we need a polynomial $R(X)$ such that
$$R(X)(1\oplus X^6\oplus X^{10})\equiv 1\pmod{X^{16}\oplus 1}.$$

You can find this using the extended Euclidean algorithm for binary polynomials or with the following sagemath code:

```
PR.<X>=PolynomialRing(GF(2))
QR.<z>=QuotientRing(PR,ideal(X^16+1))
1/(1+z^6+z^10)
```

which tells you that $R(X)=X^{14}\oplus X^{12}\oplus X^4\oplus X^2\oplus 1$. You can then convert this back to shift notation to get you decoding procedure.

Note that if one tries to generalise this, there are issues if the multiplicand shares a factor with $X^{16}\oplus 1$ in which case there is no multiplicative inverse and in fact the map is not invertible.

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer! When you say reducing "modX^16 xor 1 " you mean the modulo operation by 16?

Comment: In this case it is the same as reducing the exponents of the polynomial modulo 16 (the general rule is to take the remainder after polynomial division).